# Unexpected behaviour of chart

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, charts, victory-charts

I'm using victory(-native) to draw charts in an app, but don't understand the behaviour of a very basic chart like the following:

```
<VictoryChart
          containerComponent={<VictoryContainer />}

>



 <VictoryLine data={
  [
    {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0.51
    },
    {
      "x": -1,
      "y": 1.59
    },

    {
      "x": -3,
      "y": 3.34
    },
    {
      "x": -4,
      "y": 4.08
    },
    {
      "x": -2,
      "y": 2.93
    },
    {
      "x": -6,
      "y": 6.7
    },
    {
      "x": -7,
      "y": 7.36
    },
    {
      "x": -8,
      "y": 8.79
    },
    {
      "x": -9,
      "y": 9.42
    },
    {
      "x": -10,
      "y": 10.09
    },
    {
      "x": -11,
      "y": 11.89
    },
    {
      "x": -12,
      "y": 12.56
    },
    {
      "x": -13,
      "y": 13.25
    },
    {
      "x": -14,
      "y": 14.85
    },
    {
      "x": -15,
      "y": 15.6
    },
    {
      "x": -16,
      "y": 16.82
    },
    {
      "x": -17,
      "y": 17.04
    },
    {
      "x": -18,
      "y": 18.31
    },
    {
      "x": -19,
      "y": 19.91
    },
    {
      "x": -20,
      "y": 20.82
    },
    {
      "x": -21,
      "y": 21.77
    },
    {
      "x": -22,
      "y": 22.94
    },
    {
      "x": -23,
      "y": 23.88
    },
    {
      "x": -24,
      "y": 24
    },
    {
      "x": -25,
      "y": 25
    },
    {
      "x": -26,
      "y": 26
    },
    {
      "x": -27,
      "y": 27
    },
    {
      "x": -28,
      "y": 28.34
    },
    {
      "x": -29,
      "y": 29.94
    },
    {
      "x": -30,
      "y": 30.34
    },
    {
      "x": -31,
      "y": 31.88
    },
    {
      "x": 32,
      "y": 32.48
    },
    {
      "x": -33,
      "y": 33.95
    },
    {
      "x": -34,
      "y": 34.7
    },
    {
      "x": -35,
      "y": 35.96
    }
  ]
  }/>
</VictoryChart>
```

The expected output is a chart which shows a line from left top(-36, 35) to right bottom(0,0).

The actual output is the following:
[image: victoryChart]

**Where does the data points come from?**

To test the code, just visit [FormidableLabs](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-chart/) and paste the code under the chart.

Comment: create a fiddle/codepen of your code snippet

Comment: @student96 Chart working properly. It looks like you forgot `-` sign for data element `{ "x": 32, "y": 32.48 }`. If you add `-` it will look as you expect - https://codesandbox.io/s/k9119wy2k7